# Removing attributes in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to remove multiple attributes of an element ?Jquery documentation has only mentioned about removing a single attribute at a time.Take a reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Comment: If you read the documentation it says the parameter is *"an attribute to remove; as of version 1.7, it can be a **space-separated list of attributes**."*.

Comment: @Juhana space separated list of attributes should be within block or?

Comment: -1. Read more carefully.

Comment: @Maizere If you read the line before that it says *"Type: String"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you supplied states clearly the following about the parameter for `removeAttr`.

> An attribute to remove; as of version 1.7, it can be a space-separated list of attributes.